# Facebook : how can we maximize post Count from a particular source_id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

For now I am using the FQL to fetch facebook post from a particular source_id,

fql : SELECT post_id,message FROM stream where source_id="21540067693"

it is giving only 20 result. 
Is there a way to maximize the no. of post in result ?

Answer (score 0):

well I get a solution with graph api by myself, I am posting it may be it will be helpful for someone

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[***page_id***]/posts?access_token=[******]&limit=1000
```